# Terraform OCI Module 404-NotAutorizedOrNotFound error

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-oracle

I'm facing an issue using terraform module in my configuration (oracle Cloud). defined below block to create alarm configuration as below code, will create a file system alert for these systems.

```
module "Module_FS_Critical_env_oci_all_instance" {
  source                = "../Common/Module/FileSystem"
  compartment_id        = oci_identity_compartment.project.id
  destination           = [data.oci_ons_notification_topics.get_project_Critical_topic.notification_topics[0].topic_id]
  display_name          = "tf_Module_Critical_FS_Alarm_${each.key}"
  metric_compartment_id = oci_identity_compartment.cic_prod.id
  for_each = toset([
    oci_core_instance.env_oci_instance_01.display_name,
    oci_core_instance.env_oci_instance_02.display_name,
    oci_core_instance.env_oci_instance_03.display_name,
    oci_core_instance.env_oci_instance_04.display_name
  ])
  query = "FilesystemUtilization[5m]{resourceName = \"${each.key}\"}.mean() > 85"
}
```

Upon Apply it passed the plan check but produce the following error:

```
Error: 404-NotAuthorizedOrNotFound, Resource ocid1.onstopic.oc1.me-jeddah-1.aaaaaaaafdm2dzvukduuall5dd<truncated> could not be found or you are not authorized to access it.
│ Suggestion: Either the resource has been deleted or service Monitoring Alarm need policy to access this resource. Policy reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Reference/policyreference.htm
│ Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oracle/oci/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alarm
│ API Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/monitoring/20180401/Alarm/CreateAlarm
│ Request Target: POST https://telemetry.me-jeddah-1.oraclecloud.com/20180401/alarms
│ Provider version: 4.120.0, released on 2023-05-11.
│ Service: Monitoring Alarm
│ Operation Name: CreateAlarm
│ OPC request ID: c1f38e322c48c04acaab36db1baca20b/72E14735786558F3B/29692EC46A11C9C7A38BCF3CAC8ACC24
│
│
│   with module.Module_FS_Critical_env_oci_all_instance["instance_01"].oci_monitoring_alarm.tf_FS_Critical_FileSystem_alarm,
│   on ../Common/Module/FileSystem/fs.critical.tf line 18, in resource "oci_monitoring_alarm" "tf_FS_Critical_FileSystem_alarm":
│   18: resource "oci_monitoring_alarm" "tf_FS_Critical_FileSystem_alarm" {
```

the error indicating something wrong with destination topic, i expected the data block but its ok and able to retrieve the ID of the topic, also tried to create resource block and it didn't work with same error, its more likely that module not able to get the topic. i need hits on how to resolve this error as i'm stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check IAM policies?

```
Allow group <group_name> to manage ons-topics in tenancy
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/commonpolicies.htm#top

Comment: terraform user is part of Administrators group, and the issue is only when using module, so using resource block is ok the result achieved.